# how to format a number in mIRC?

Tags: number-formatting, mirc

My remote script gets a variable with a number formatted like `4365271385`.
I would like the script to send a message with the variable in it formatted like `4.365.271.385`.

I searched the internet and the help file, but i couldn't find it.
Sometimes the number is in the thousands, sometimes in the billions.

How to do this? Can't be hard, can it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is indeed not very hard. Use `$bytes`, in your case `$bytes(4365271385,bd)`

- b parameter: Comma-formats the number for bytes.
- d parameter: Returns the value whilst retaining decimal point values. You don't need this if you're only working with whole integers. But it's handy to have.

More at http://en.wikichip.org/wiki/mirc/identifiers/$bytes

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thanks for your help!